# How to apply 2 min difference between two threads

Tags: jmeter

I have 100 number of threads in Thread group, want to send 1 HTTPS request without any delay after that 2 min delay between next request.

e.g. 1 request then 2 min delay again 1 request then 2 min delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use constant timer to put a constant delay of 2 min between the requests.

**For while Loop problem see below:-**

You need to reset the counter. Use JSR223 Sample to reset the value to something else then expected.

In the below plan, I have used counter 1-5 and used it in while loop as ${__javaScript("${counter}" != "5",)}. After that using JSR223 to reset the value again to 1 for next iteration.

[image]

Comment: In my test plan 2 HTTP request I want when I start the script 1 thread is executed in this thread both HTTP request executed then 2 min delay again 2nd thread execute and again both HTTP request should excite

Comment: Use "Test Action" sampler if you want to delay execution for 2 min after sending both 2 HTTP Requests. Put it below the two requests and enter the duration 120000 millisecond (2min)

Comment: the request within while loop is not executed when I used Test Action

Comment: Updated my answer for while loop issue

Answer (score 0):

To provide delay of 2 minutes 
for 
100 user you need to 
set 
Rampup period :100 (Thread Group)
and
Thread delay : 120000 ms (Constant Timer)

You can use Timer here I have used Constant Timer for delay between Threads. Refer Below image for more understanding. here for 3 miniutes.

[Constant Timer Tutorial](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/jmeter-tutorials/constant-timer-in-jmeter-example)

[Ramp up Period Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide)

[image: Constant Timer Example]

Comment: I want a delay between threads not between HTTP request. I think constant timer apply delay between each request

Comment: @KuldeepYadav you can user Test Action Sampler and use the reference link [Reference link](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers) let me know if you stuck

Comment: the request within while loop is not executed (2nd time) when I used Test Action

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following Test Plan structure:

- [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

  - HTTP Request

    - Synchronizing Timer
  - [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) Sampler configured to "Pause" for `120000` milliseconds (2 minutes)

    - [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer)

The "Number of Simulated Users to Group by" setting of the Synchronizing Timer should be equal to the number of threads (virtual users) in the Thread Group